# How can I display data which are the addition of all "Price" multiply with "amountt"?

Tags: php, html

I cant get the idea on how to get "Total Price" by adding all of the rows which are multiplication of "Price" and "amount"

```
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["FoodID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Foodname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Price"] . "</td><td>" . "<input type='number' min='0' id='amountt' />" . "</td><td>";
            
        }
    }
    else {
            echo "No Results Found.";
        }

    echo "<label for='amountt'>Total Price = </label>" . $row["Price"] * "value[id='amountt']";

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to sum the price of each row in your while loop first `$sum += $row['Price'];` and then multiply it by amount after the loop's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have rows of price and amount, you can calculate the product price by multiplying price and amount. The product price will just be the price of one product (but can be multiple items). And to get total price you can sum all product prices together.

For example,

```
$totalPrice = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $productPrice = $row['price'] * $row['amount'];
    $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $productPrice;
}
```

Then you can apply this loop to your problem. You can create a new variable `$productPrice` and `$totalPrice` or you can omit `$productPrice` altogether like below.

```
$totalPrice = $totalPrice + ($row['price'] * $row['amount']);
```

or just

```
$totalPrice += $row[['price'] * $row['amount'];
```

Comment: Thank you! but it seems I can't declare the **$row['amount']** as it is from an input textbox instead of the database, is there any way to declare the number inserted in the textbox by the user as a variable to be used?

Comment: the number inserted in the textbox will be passed with form to $_POST variable by its name e.g. $_POST['amount'], $_POST['input'], etc.